Signature Verification fails while using adb sideload <device_firm_ware_file.zip> ; Techno Device
DM-verity of my Techno Device Model Gk-8/Gk-8-Gl just got expired and my device is unable to boot into its OS.
I decided to update it system and use an updated firmware zip file downloaded from trusted place AndroidMTK. Everything goes perfectly until I run a command
adb sideload <device_firmware_file.zip>

My device displays an error :
Supported API-3
finding_package_update....
verifying package update...
E: footer is wrong
Update package verification took 0.2s (result - 1)
E:Signature verification failed
E: error : 21

I have tried to fix this issue by creating my own disable verity zip file and when I try to sideload that I get that same error; I think it would be very helpful if I get some information about how to resolve this issue?
